# Randomly selecting 2 integers not in a range?

Tags: c++, random, int

I'm new to C++, and I've been searching all day to find a way to randomly select one of two distinct integers.

Everything I've found so far works only for integers within a range (1-10, etc) rather than for (1 **or** 3).

For ex. code I've been using elsewhere in the program (for a range of numbers) is

```
int c;
int Min = 1;
int Max = 3;
c = rand() % (Max + 1 - Min) + Min;
```

which returns a random integer within the range, rather than one or the other integers given.

Comment: what? what about the range? Do you mean to select between two integers? Then what does a range have to do with it?

Comment: This is a confusing question...

Comment: Yes, to select randomly between two integers. Range doesn't have anything to do with it, just that everything I've found gives me the expression to select numbers **within** a range, rather than two completely unrelated integers

Comment: `rand() & 1 ? Min : Max;`

Comment: Create an array, and index over it.

Comment: @liliscent, could you give an example code how to do this?

Comment: Find out how many alternatives (n) there are (in your case, two), then generate a number in the range 1..n and then pick the right alternative accordingly.

Comment: @Borgleader, my understanding is that will give me a range  between the min and the max integers, which isn't what I'm looking for - am I misunderstanding?

Comment: `array_index = rand() % array_count;`

Comment: @mnistic, would that look something like

`int arr[2] = {1, 3};
    arr_index = rand() % arr_count;
    c = arr_index;`
--->c is now the randomly selected integer?

Comment: you really need to edit your question to clarify what you want. As you see an answer understood you want an integer in `(-∞, 0] or [4 to ∞)`.

Comment: @tevyefegeleh You are this will give you `Min` or `Max` depending on whether `rand()` returns an even or odd number.

Comment: edited for clarity, I've found an answer that works but hopefully this may help others with the same question as well, thank you everyone for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Randomly choosing one of two integers, a or b:

```
c = (rand() % 2) ? a : b
```

Randomly choosing an integer from a list of integers:

```
std::vector<int> numbers;
c = numbers.at(rand() % numbers.size());
```

Randomly choosing an integer from two intervals [a, b) and [c, d):

```
H = (b-a);
L = (b-a) + (d-c);
k = rand() % L;
c = (k < H) ? (a + k) : (c + (k - H));
```

In case you do C++11 then you may definitely have look into [pseudo-random numer generation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random), like [discrete_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution) and [uniform_int_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution).

*Update.* Removed the claim that we would choose uniformly from the given set. Since rand() chooses from [0, RAND_MAX], this is only true if the divisor of the above modulo operations divides (RAND_MAX+1). (Which is true for the first example in most implementations where RAND_MAX is 32767 or another power-of-two minus 1.) However, the defect from being uniform is roughly of the order of divisor/RAND_MAX. Nevertheless, C++11 [uniform_int_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) is recommended instead. Thanks, Baum mit Augen.

Comment: [Another fun trick is to `shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) the `vector` and take the first element.

Comment: This is *not* uniformly random unless the right operand of your modulus operator divides `RAND_MAX`.

Comment: Hm, it must divide `RAND_MAX + 1` actually. Anyways, the point stands.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you shouldn't use C random in C++. Use C++ random.

The way to chose from a set of elements is to randomly generate an index. You can wrap the logic in a class:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list>

class Random_choice
{
    std::random_device rd_{};

public:
    template <class T> auto get_choice(std::initializer_list<T> elements) -> T
    {
        std::uniform_int_distribution<std::size_t> dist{0, elements.size() - 1};
        std::size_t i = dist(rd_);

        return *(elements.begin() + i);
    }
};


int main()
{
    Random_choice rc;

    std::cout << rc.get_choice({3, 5}) << std::endl;
}
```

Or without the abstraction:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> choices = {3, 5};

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 e{rd()};
    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::size_t> dist{0, choices.size() - 1};

    std::size_t i = dist(e);

    std::cout << choices[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a range of numbers that you don't want numbersin, then you have *two* ranges that you *do* want numbers in.

For example, if your range is 1 to 3 (inclusive) then the two ranges you do want numbers in are -∞ to 0, and 4 to ∞.

Infinity is a little tricky on computers, but can easily be emulated for example by [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) to get the min and max for the wanted type.

So in your case you want a random number in the range `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()` to `0`, and `4` to `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`.

Two get two random numbers from a random choice of either range, first pick (randomly) one range, and get a number from that. Then again (randomly) pick a range and get the second number from that.

Comment: Take care so you pick one of the ranges with the proper probability in case they are not equally big.

Comment: I don't think that's what he meant